# Magento - How to get products that have a category

Tags: php, magento

I need the last 4 products created, that are in a category. 
I use this code, to get all products and sort them by date created, but it returns the products, that aren't in any category too, any suggestions? Thank you!

```
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
    $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc')
                    ->setPageSize(4);
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($products);
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($products);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$_rootcatID = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();

$_testproductCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
->joinField('category_id','catalog/category_product','category_id','product_id=entity_id',null,'left')

 ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('neq' => 0))

->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$_testproductCollection->load();
```

Comment: it gives me this error: Item (Mage_Catalog_Model_Product) with the same id "9" already exist